# wget corrupted file .zip file error

Tags: wget

I am using wget to try and download two .zip files (`SWVF_1_44.zip` and `SWVF_44_88.zip`) from this site:  http://www2.sos.state.oh.us/pls/voter/f?p=111:1:0::NO:RP:P1_TYPE:STATE

when I run:

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off "http://www2.sos.state.oh.us/pls/voter/f?p=111:1:0::NO:RP:P1_TYPE:STATE/SWVF_1_44.zip"
```

I get a downloaded zip file that has a screwed up name `(f@p=111%3A1%3A0%3A%3ANO%3ARP%3AP1_TYPE%3ASTATE%2FSWVF_1_44)` and it cannot be opened.

Any thoughts on where my code is wrong?

Comment: Found the answer! The site was actually linking to a ftp by which I had to call that url and not the webpage url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing "wrong" with your code. Wget is simply assuming you want to save the file in the same name that appears in the url. Use the `-O` option to specify an output file:

```
wget blahblahblah -O useablefilename.zip
```

Comment: still getting the corrupted file issue.  Have any idea what is the cause?

Comment: It seems the folder downloaded is empty.  Is this due to the website or my wget call?

Comment: Found the answer!  THe site was actually linking to a ftp by which I had to call that url and not the webpage url.